# Map and onKeyDown event

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a web page with a map and search field. Something like [Derek's "beer's finder"](http://swingley.appspot.com/maps/beers)
When I type a search request I somethimes use arrows to fix something. But if mouse is over the map, then I can't use arrows for text editing because map catches them. I tried to fix it the following way (without result):

```
    dojo.connect(this._currentmap, "onKeyDown", function(ev) {
        if (ev.keyCode >= 37 && ev.keyCode <= 40) { //if arrrow
            dojo.stopEvent(ev);
        }
    });
```

Do you know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: please check out the dojo.keys namespace and convert to using that for readability etc. http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/keys.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try calling [map.disableKeyboardNavigation()](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/map.htm#disbleKeyboardNavigation) when the search field gets focus, and enableKeyboardNavigation() on blur.